# Creating 3D model using set of 2D images on Windows

Tags: opengl-to-opengles, 3d-modelling

I want to create a 3D model using set of 2D images on windows which can be send through webservice to iphone to display on it.
I know it can be done through Opengl but don't know how to start and also if I succeeded in creating it,is it compatible with iphone as iphone uses opengl es.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of transformation do you have in mind to create the 3D models? I once worked on an application using such a concept to create a model from three images of an object. It didn't really work well. The models that could be created were very limited.
OpenGL does not have a built in functionality to do such stuff. Are there any reasosns why you do not want to use a real 3D-model? It sounds as if you are looking for a fast solution for your problem. But I'm afraid if you do not have any OpenGL experience, you should prepare prepare for lots of stuff  to learn.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create 3D models automatically from 2D photos, you're going to have a fair bit of work to do. AFAIK, this is not something where you can get a cheap pre-packaged solution. Autodesk charge a small fortune for ImageModeler.

[MeshLab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/) may be a good starting point, but even that can't automatically convert photos to a 3D model AFAIK.

Take a look at [David Lowe](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/)s site. I found the "Distinctive image features from scale-invariant keypoints" paper quite interesting, though I haven't re-read it in a while. If nothing else, this should give you some idea why this is far from a trivial problem.